# /README.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with CRLF line terminators

Tags: coding-standards

I have been working on a Drupal.org project and I want to make sure that pass all the coding standards. For some reason I got these problem with the README.txt encoding and I dont know how to solve it.

```
 ./README.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with CRLF line terminators README.txt
```

- Bad line endings were found, always use unix style terminators
- ./README.txt: the byte order mark at the beginning of UTF-8 files is discouraged, you should remove it.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ? I'm currently using Sublime Text 2 and I save my README.txt as UTF-8 Unicode with BOM and this did not fix my problem.

Here is the README.txt https://gist.github.com/darol100/e24059dbacc4f7e205ad
http://pareview.sh/pareview/httpgitdrupalorgsandboxdarol1002309319git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Settings - User config, you should set

```
"default_line_ending": "unix",
```

Also, when saving file, select UTF-8 Unicode **without** BOM - that's exactly what you were told here:

> the **b**​yte **o**​rder **m**​ark at the beginning of UTF-8 files is discouraged

Emphasis mine.

Taken from [Fixing Sublime Text 2 line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11899843)